# Override Dotenv settings before config/database.php is parsed via a service provider

Tags: laravel

I have a multi-tenant application where the tenant is determined by the `HTTP_HOST` in the request. This is decided in a service provider which is the first thing listed in `config/app.php` `providers` array.

In this service provider, I overload the env variables with the following:

```
public function boot(Request $request)
{
    $tenant = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
    $dotenv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(base_path('sites' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $tenant . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config'));
    $dotenv->overload();
}
```

Basically, look in the `sites/site_name/config` folder for a .env file. This also works fine, if I run `php artisan tinker` and echo out an env variable like `env('DATABASE_USER')`. The issue lies with the database not reading from this overloaded env file. Does the database service read the config in `config/database.php` before any of the service provider `boot` methods run?

I've done this:

```
Config::set('database.default', 'mysql');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', env('DB_HOST'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.port', env('DB_PORT'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', env('DB_DATABASE'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', env('DB_USERNAME'));
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', env('DB_PASSWORD'));
```

which works, but is there a better way to bootstrap the env file earlier in the process to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change which `.env` file to load in **`bootstrap/app.php`**. After `$app`* has been created, use the method `useEnvironmentPath($path)`. The original `.env` in your project will be completely ignored.

You might not have access to the Request object in this file, so use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

### Command Line

If you want to change on the command line too, check that PHP_SAPI is 'cli' and retrieve tenant via command option:

```php
<?php
if(PHP_SAPI === 'cli') { 
    $tenant = (new ArgvInput())->getParameterOption('--tenant');
} else {
    $tenant = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}

if(empty($tenant) === false) {
    $app->useEnvironmentPath("/path/to/$tenant/config/")
}
```

You would need to add the --tenant into your Console\Application as default command option. Modify `App\Console\Kernel::getArtisan()` to return an `Illuminate\Console\Application` extended object.

**app/Console/Kernel.php**

```php
<?php
# [...]

protected function getArtisan()
{
    if (is_null($this->artisan)) {
        return $this->artisan = (new \App\Console\Application($this->app, $this->events, $this->app->version()))
            ->resolveCommands($this->commands);
    }

    return $this->artisan;
}
```

**app/Console/Application.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Application as Artisan;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class Application extends Artisan 
{
    protected function getDefaultInputDefinition()
    {
        $definition = parent::getDefaultInputDefinition();

        $definition->addOption(new InputOption('--tenant', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, "Tenant to be used");

        return $definition;
    }
}
```

* You will also have to override the cache path for Laravel config. Its in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedConfigPath()`, so extend this class and use that class instead in `bootstrap/app.php`.